# Cannot download files from WordPress site on Chrome but works fine on Safari and Firefox

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I run a WordPress site where we have some .docx files available for download to our subscribers. Much to my surprise, I was unable to download these .docx files on Chrome - I tested this out on two computers, tested with different accounts and tested in both regular and Incognito Mode. When I hit the download button, the page attempts to go to the specific download page address but then ends up just refreshing and doing nothing. I also attempted to enable the option where downloads open in a new tab but when I click "download" in this case, a new table briefly opens and immediately closes without pulling anything up.

As mentioned in the title, I have absolutely zero problems downloading the files on Safari or Firefox. Furthermore, the downloads were working perfectly on Chrome a couple days ago but now everything seems broken, both with the new files I uploaded and the old files that were already there.

Does anyone have any suspicions as to what may be the cause of this and what I can do to remedy it? It seems like this is more of a Chrome issue than WordPress issue.

Comment: If you open the page with the developer console active and try to download the file, is there any difference between FF and Chrome?

Comment: I also have a problem happening only on Chrome and it appeared when Chrome updated to version 91. What is your version of Chrome ?